# Unit testing EJB and remote interface with EjbEmbedded Conatiner

Tags: unit-testing, jndi, ejb-3.1

I have this EJB

```
@Stateless
public class HelloBean{


    public String sayHello(){
        return "hello";
    } 

}
```

When I test with this unit test:

```
    @Test
    public void testEmbeddedPersistence() throws NamingException {
        assertTrue(true);



        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        props.put(EJBContainer.MODULES,  new File("target/classes"));
        props.put("org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.glassfish.instance.root",    "./src/test/resources/glassfish-testing-domain");

    ec = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(props);
    ctx = ec.getContext();


    String s = "java:global/classes/HelloBean";
    HelloBean helloBean = (HelloBean) ctx.lookup(s);
    assertNotNull(helloBean);

    assertABunchOfStuff();        

    ec.close();
}
```

everything works fine.

But when I change it to

```
@Stateless
public class HelloBean implements RemoteHello{


    public String sayHello(){
            return "hello";
    }
}

@Remote
public interface RemoteHello{
    public String sayHello();
}





@Test
    public void testEmbeddedPersistence() throws NamingException {
        assertTrue(true);



        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        props.put(EJBContainer.MODULES,  new File("target/classes"));
        props.put("org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.glassfish.instance.root", "./src/test/resources/glassfish-testing-domain");

        ec = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(props);
        ctx = ec.getContext();


        String s = "java:global/classes/HelloBean!com.mycompany.remoteInterface.RemoteHello";
        RemoteHello remoteHello = (RemoteHello) ctx.lookup(s);
        assertNotNull(remoteHello);

        assertABunchOfStuff();        

        ec.close();
    }
```

I get a javax.naming.NamingException

the weirdest thing is, When the EJBContainer is intializing it says:

INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB HelloBean: [java:global/classes/HelloBean!com.mycompany.remoteInterface.RemoteHello, java:global/classes/HelloBean]
Feb 10, 2012 3:55:22 PM com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer initializeHome

followed shortly after:

Tests in error: 
  testEmbeddedPersistence(com.mycompaony.HelloBean): Lookup failed for 'java:global/classes/HelloBean!com.mycompany.remoteInterface.RemoteHello' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}

How can I get a successful jndi lookup with a remote interface.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote interfaces are not part of EJB lite (EJB 3.1 specification, table 27), and embeddable containers are only required to provide EJB lite (EJB 3.1 specification, section 22.3.1).